# Creating a new post on in wordpress via python and wordress_xmlrpc

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I want use python and wordpress_xmlrpc to automate posting on my wordpress site.

This is the code that i'm using:

```
import json
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost, GetPosts

wp = Client('http://localhost/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'this is my post'
post.content = 'this is mt content'
post.terms_name = {
        'post_tag': ['test', 'firstpost'],
        'category': ['tes']
}
wp.call (NewPost(post))
```

The error that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    wp = Client('http://localhost/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')
  File "/home/danreznik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wordpress_xmlrpc/base.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.supported_methods = self.server.mt.supportedMethods()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1109, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1450, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1153, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1169, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1341, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 655, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32700: 'parse error. not well formed'>
```

What am I doing wrog and how to fix this?